# How install rvm on server that already have ruby install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have a server that runs rails app on ruby version 1.8.7. I now want to add one more that written on ruby 2.0.0.
Can I install rvm on this server?

Answer (score -1):

The the following
    $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash